Anime about a world where green sparkles came falling from the sky, giving a bunch of people superpowers
Before I start, I'm going to clarify I have a vague memory of this anime. It was an anime with a 3D art style and went heavy on the CGI. It was a little old, but I can't say for sure.
It was about a world where these green sparkles came falling from the sky, giving a bunch of people superpowers. Some of them became heroes, some became villains.
I can remember there was this rich man who had a suit and was basically Iron Man, but his suit was all blue and he had an OST which was either called "Sky Fall" or "Star Fall." The OST cover was what seemed to be an old man, the name of the song or anime in the bottom middle and half of it was pink, the other half was blue.
There was another hero I remember. It was what seemed to be a Spider-Man suit, but it was all red and he had a different ability I can't remember.
In the middle of some episodes, it would switch to the life of a few Japanese schoolgirls talking a trip to the USA. At the end, the outro would be those Japanese schoolgirls dancing.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And did you watch it on TV? If so, in which country, and do you recall which channel or channels it might have been on?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAXF-LAujCE, so not fish then

Is this The Reflection (2017)...?
It's a 12-episode anime series co-created by Stan Lee and Hiroshi Nagahama. The animation includes 3D elements, but the cel shaded art style makes it look mostly 2D.
The story is set three years after a catastrophic global event known as the Reflection, during which green light and black smoke rained down from the sky. Most people touched by the light or smoke died, but the survivors gained powers and are known as the Reflected. The Reflected touched by the light became heroes, while those touched by the smoke became villains.
Some brief shots of the event can be seen near the start of this trailer.



One of the most prominent heroes on the show, I-Guy, wears blue power armour vaguely resembling Iron Man's. In his civilian life, he's Ian Izzet, an English pop star based in Los Angeles who had a hit single called "Sky Show" back in the '80s. He loves being in the public spotlight and broadcasts "Sky Show" with his armour whenever he's in action as I-Guy.


The Reflection - S01E04 - "New Orleans"

"Sky Show" is included in the OST and was recorded by musician and record producer Trevor Horn, who appears in the show as Ian Izzet's record producer. A video of the track can be viewed on Trevor Horn's YouTube channel, with a background image matching your description of I-Guy's OST cover. The face in the image is that of Trevor Horn, as depicted in the show.



Another prominent hero, X-On, wears a red costume vaguely resembling Spider-Man's, and can duplicate the powers of the Reflected after a few seconds of physical contact with them. He seems to retain these powers indefinitely and one of them enables him to project energy ropes from his wrists, reminiscent of Spider-Man's webbing.


The Reflection - S01E01 - "Ceremony"

Most of the action takes place in the US, but there are scenes in Japan centred around four schoolgirls. These characters are based on Kanae Yoshii, Hirona Murata, Uki Satake and Sayaka Nishiwaki, four members of the Japanese idol group, 9nine, who provided the voicework for the characters.


The Reflection - S01E01 - "Ceremony"

Those four members of 9nine also recorded "SunSunSunrise," the Jpop track that plays over the outro for each episode, and their silhouettes are shown dancing in the outro.



